# Short circuiting constraints on a field in hibernate validator

Tags: annotations, hibernate-validator

I want the constraints on fields of a class to be ordered and short-circuit, e.g.

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "Name length improper")
@Pattern(regexp = "T.*", message = "Name doesn't start with T")
private String name;
```

with `name="S"`, should fail the `@Size` constraint and hence not even bother checking the next one. I went through Groups, `GroupSequence` and Composite Constraints but nothing seems to be of use. Specifically, `GroupSequence` will not work for my case. Consider this:

```
public class Bean {

  public interface First{}
  public interface Second {}

  @GroupSequence({First.class, Second.class})
  public interface Sequence {}

  public Bean(String name, int noOfDependants) {
  ...
  }

  @Size(min = 2, max = 10, groups = {First.class})
  @Pattern(regexp = "T.*", groups = {Second.class})
  private String name;

  @Min(value = 0, groups = {First.class})
  @Max(value = 4, groups = {Second.class})
  private int noOfDependants;
}
validator.validate(new Bean("S", 5), Sequence.class)
```

I expect the first constraint on `name` and second constraint on `noOfDependants` to fail. But the way GroupSequence works, the First.class group would fail and Second.class wouldn't even be executed.

Finally, I decided to write my own constraint like so:

```
@LazySequence({
    @Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "Name length improper"),
    @Pattern(regexp = "T.*", message = "Name doesn't start with T")
})
private String name;
```

and hit the familiar problem [Annotation member which holds other annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679177/annotation-member-which-holds-other-annotations)

```
public @interface LazySequence {
    ???[] values();
    String message() default "";
    ...
 }
```

Has anyone encountered this use case?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the question you linked, there can only be annotation members of a concrete annotation type, so there is no way you could implement `@LazySequence` in the intended way.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "short-circuit", but based on your description I think using group sequences still should work:

```
public class Bean {

    public interface First {}

    public interface Second {}

    @GroupSequence({First.class, Second.class})
    public interface Sequence {}

    @Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "Name length improper", groups = { First.class })
    @Pattern(regexp = "T.*", message = "Name doesn't start with T" , groups = { Second.class })
    private String name;

}
```

When now validating a `Bean` instance using the defined sequence (`validator.validate(bean, Sequence.class)`), at first the `@Size` constraint will be validated and only if that succeeds the `@Pattern` constraint.

You can learn more about validation groups and group sequences in the Bean Validation [specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence) and the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups).

Comment: I have updated my example above to explain why GroupSequence wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: But couldn't you just change the groups of the `@Max` and `@Min` constraints then? When validating the `@Sequence` group sequence, at first `@Size` and `@Max` would be validated, and just then `@Pattern` and `@Min`.

Comment: I want to maintain the ordering of constraints on a field too e.g. I want `@Min` to execute before `@Max`. Maybe this contrived example is not justifying my need; essentially I need "ordering" as well as "lazy"/"fail- fast" (whatever you choose to call it) constraint checking on each field.

Comment: That's exactly what group sequences are intended for. If required you might even put each constraint into its own group. If `@Min` should be validated before `@Max` then put the constraints in appropriate groups. I think it's best if you exactly describe the behavior you want to accomplish based on the example you gave and what cases you think are not covered by group sequences. Maybe it's also worth pointing out that you can work with [inheritence](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupinheritance) when defining validation groups.

Comment: I have a very similar problem as [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285070/groupsequence-and-ordered-evaluation-in-jsr-303](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285070/groupsequence-and-ordered-evaluation-in-jsr-303). I understand that the answer provided at the aforementioned link is a possible solution. However, I feel the class will become too cluttered and hard-to-follow if it contains 10 fields, each having 3 constraints or so.

Comment: Also, if there are multiple beans to be validated then the above solution will result in invocations of `validator.validate(...)` being specific to a bean. It wouldn't be agnostic to the bean being validated.

Comment: You might [override](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-redefiningdefaultgroup) the beans' default group sequences to address this problem.