# Bean validation specification prioritizing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bean-validation

I am using bean validation specification to validate my form on spring-boot thymeleaf project. 
My entity property is as follow.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{Password should not be empty}")
@Pattern(regexp = //Pattern for range 1-20, message = "{Wrong Input}")
private String            password;
```

When I run and inputed to password field of my form with empty value, both of Validation Error Messages were shown.

My expectation is, while empty value is inputed, only @NotEmpty annotation should work and on the other hand, only @Pattern should be shown upon user input is wrong.

How can I do with Bean Validation Specification for that?

Regards.

Comment: Can you show what regex pattern you are using in @Pattern ?

Comment: @Gaurav my actual pattern what I am using in my source is **(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=\\S+$).{8,20}**

Comment: Can you give a sample string that you expect to pass this regex ?

Comment: This is the sample string **test123User**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. [Validation groups](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintdefinition-groups)

```
@NotEmpty(groups = First.class), message = ...,          
@Pattern(groups = Second.class, regexp = ...)
private String password;
```

Create the validation groups:

```
//Validation Groups - Just empty interface used as Group identifier
public interface First {
}
public interface Second {
}
```

and validate the model this way:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Model>> violations = validator.validate(model, First.class);

if(violations.isEmpty()){
     violations = validator.validate(model, Second.class);
}
```

## 2. [Groups Sequences](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupsequence)

I've never used them, but it seems it does just what you want

Check this other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7779681/641627). I've added below a quote from this answer (from **@Gunnar**), which ironically also uses **First** and **Second** group names:

> ```
> @GroupSequence({First.class, Second.class})
> public interface Sequence {}
>
> @Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "Name length improper", groups = { First.class })
> @Pattern(regexp = "T.*", message = "Name doesn't start with T" , groups = { Second.class })
> private String name;
> ```
>
> When now validating a Bean instance using the defined sequence
>   (validator.validate(bean, Sequence.class)), at first the @Size
>   constraint will be validated and only if that succeeds the @Pattern
>   constraint.

With this solution, you wouldn't need to manually call validator.validate(...), the validations would be performed in the order defined in the Sequence with short-circuit if one fails.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't get on what First.class and Second.class mean. 
What actually are they?

Comment: I've edited the part (1) with First & Second definition. They are just empty interfaces that you need to create, just to use them as Group Identifier.