# Java Bean validation and regex - format and length in two different error message

Tags: java, regex, bean-validation

For example, input is phone number. Format is

(country code)(space)(area code)(space)(phone number)

Area code can be blank.

```
e.g.
63 240 1234567   (valid)
63 1234567  (valid)
```

What regex pattern do I need so I can have it check if all characters are numeric and if the phone number (without country and area code) is of a certain length?

and is it possible that using only one pattern, I can have two distinct error messages for two distinct invalid input:
1. All characters should be numeric
2. Actual Phone number length should be 7 to 10.

because we currently have it this way

```
@Pattern(regexp=" some regex pattern", message="phone is invalid")
private String phoneNumber
```

I could add a @Size validator but I only need to trim out the phone number.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression could work:

```
^(\d{2})\s(?:(\d{3})\s)?(\d{7,10})$
```

### Explanation:

- `^` Begining of string
- `(\d{2})\s` 2 digits, followed by a space (country code)(space)
- `(?:(\d{3})\s)?` (optional) 3 digits, followed by a space (area code)(space)
- `(\d{7,10})` 7 to 10 digits
- `$` End of string

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/Mqpdx6/1)

### Limitations:

- It will match things like `63 240 1234567` and `63 1234567` but it wouldn't match `631234567` or `63 240 1234567`, it's expecting a space after each of those sections. It's easy to work around those limitations, but it depends on the level of validation you require. If spaces are optional, you could replace both `\s` by `\s?`

### Variant

If you want all the spaces and the country code to be optional, here's a variant: `^(?:(\d{2})\s?)?(?:(\d{3})\s?)?(\d{7,10})$`

### Code Sample

If you would like to evaluate both patterns, in sequential order, you could go with this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603564/7400458), for the Java code, combined with the two regex above.

> ```
> @GroupSequence({First.class, Second.class})
> public interface Sequence {}
>
> @Size(min = 2, max = 10, message = "Name length improper", groups = { First.class })
> @Pattern(regexp = "T.*", message = "Name doesn't start with T" , groups = { Second.class })
> private String name;
> ```
>
> When now validating a Bean instance using the defined sequence
>   (validator.validate(bean, Sequence.class)), at first the @Size
>   constraint will be validated and only if that succeeds the @Pattern
>   constraint.

Something like that:

```
 @GroupSequence({First.class, Second.class})
 public interface Sequence {}

 @Pattern(regexp = "^[ \d]+$", message = "Numeric input required" , groups = { First.class })
 @Pattern(regexp = "^(?:(\d{2})\s?)?(?:(\d{3})\s?)?(\d{7,10})$", message = "Phone no. should be 7-10 in length" , groups = { Second.class })
 private String phoneNumber;
```

Comment: using one regex can only return one error message right? what if we want two separate invalid error messages for "numeric input required" and "phone no. should be 7-10 in length". ?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Java to give you a full code, but my guess is that you would need to evaluate the string with two different tests. A test of digits and spaces would look like `^[ \d]+$` and a test for a certain number of digits would be similar to what I gave you. If you make the spaces optionnal, then you'd be able to only evaluate how many digits are present in the string. It's the number in between the `{}`

Comment: If you follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41603564/7400458), there's a discussion about ways of coding more than one test, in bean-validation. With the regex I gave you, you should be able to evaluate both. They talk about two different ways of doing it, so you might want to decide wich way you prefer.